# Error when read reviews from Google My Business REST API

Tags: google-my-business-api

FIrst I get the access token, then I run command in Postman/Insomnia. Below is the cURL version:

```
curl --request GET \
  --url https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/103754858715037057901/locations/ChIJfSoYcTGuEmsR1Vs1rPs6WRw/reviews \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer ya29.a0AfH6SMCfj3Ekjj8qwudOSYqIj8cEcHvtpyLyQ1SRFvQc62ItV7ph2PJeFLqIzuh41IxDKmel348DerYSQx-AaxcNw_7iYmWcSZUfl85uiZK_SOMEACCESSTOKEN_GpBAFXeVbGWeCPjyk1BjF8spjmQzNO' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --header 'X-GOOG-API-FORMAT-VERSION: 2'
```

But I get error like below:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.mybusiness.v4.ValidationError",
        "errorDetails": [
          {
            "code": 3,
            "message": "Resource could not be found"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What did I missed here?
The account already enable the API and billing.

Comment: Just a guess, but usually the locationID value is all numeric like say `/locations/0123456789/reviews`, but yours is an alpha numeric string `locations/ChIJfSoYcTGuEmsR1Vs1rPs6WRw/reviews`.

Comment: Hi. Yes, in my case that was the case. I need to request to get the profile ID first, then request for list of location IDs using the profile ID.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, the issue was a bad locationID value? If yes, and you have solved it, you should write up an answer :)

Comment: Yep, added an answer to help others or my future self in case I forgot.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the problem was incorrect Location ID. I was under impression that Place ID is same with Location ID, it's not. Place ID is alpha-numeric, and Location ID is numeric-only

To get location ID, you need to:

- Get Profile ID, then
- Get list of Location IDs that belong to that Profile ID

After getting the correct Location ID, I get can the reviews

Answer (score 1):

Permana is correct that you need the Profile ID and not the Place ID. I would like to add to Permana's answer to make it easier for others to find the Profile ID. The Profile ID can be found by logging into the Business Profile Manager -> Businesses (left-hand side at the bottom) and then clicking on the "See your profile" button. Doing so will open up Google search. Click on the three dots next to "Your business on Google" -> Business Profile Settings -> Advanced Settings.

Comment: Thanks man, wasted 2 hours in this :(

Comment: Glad it helped you, Niranjan. At least it wasn't 3 hours!